# The conseqence of reformat in GIT, how to improve?

Tags: git, coding-style

Let's suppose we have a very large project and lot's of people working on it. Due to the different IDE setting and lack of control of code style. The format of code was a mess. So I want to use some auto format tool to make it looks better.

The problem is, after the reformat. It is hard to compare two versions one is before the reformat and another is after the reformat.

Further more. If the project has some branches. If I do the reformat on one branch(main branch). The other branch is still in the old format. When it merge back to the main branch, the conflict could be tremendous.

So, is there a way or a tool to make reformat of code easier or feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would have done :

Create a **master_reformat** branch form your master, just in case you would mess it up. Reformat it as you wish and commit your changes on it.

Then, checkout a dev branch, and merge **master_reformat** onto it. If it doesn't raise any conflicts (it is possible if your reformat isn't too heavy) then you can merge **master_reformat** on master, and on each dev branch. If it raises a lot of conflicts, you might want to lighten your reformat rules.

You might also want each dev team to make this merge by themselves on their branches, just in case it raises an awful conflict. But if your reformat isn't too intrusive on the code, you shouldn't have any problems (I mean if it just replace all tabs with 2 spaces, this should be smooth).